# script to rename folders & files based on input files

Tags: bash, file-rename

I exported folders and files from a document management system and what I got is a collection of folders and nested files & folders that have random names. Each folder and file has a descriptor file with extension .esw that contains a variable called SHORTNAME that holds the true folder and file name. My challenge is to now rename those folders and files back to their true name.

I found a script that does this but it stops at line 13 where it says "$0". The only change I made is to rem out the dos2unix utility as I don't have it and don't know what it does either.

Any tips how to get this working in shell or vbs?

```
#!/bin/sh 

for fl in $(ls) 
do 
flo="$(echo $fl | sed s/\.esw//)" 
if [ -d $flo ] 
then 
echo "cd $flo" 
echo "$0" 
echo "cd -" 
cd $flo 
$0 
cd - 
echo "checking $fl" 
#    dos2unix -q -n $fl $fl 
# Remove empty spaces and nonsense from description (replace with "_") 
sd="$(cat $fl | grep SHORTDESC | sed s/\SHORTDESC=// | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed    
s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ 
/_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\\./_/)" 
rm $fl 
if [[ "$sd" = '' ]] 
then 
  echo "won't do that" 
else 
  echo "mv $flo $sd" 
  mv $flo $sd 
fi 
else 
echo "$fl" > $$.tmp 
if cat $$.tmp | grep esw > /dev/null 
then 
  rm $$.tmp 
  if cat $fl | grep SHORTDESC > /dev/null 
  then 
    #dos2unix -q -n $fl $fl 
    ex="$(cat $fl | grep DOCEXT | sed s/\DOCEXT=\.//)" 
    sd="$(cat $fl | grep SHORTDESC | sed s/\SHORTDESC=// | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | 
 sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed 
s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\ /_/ | sed s/\\./_/)" 
    rm $fl 
    echo "rm $fl" 
    echo "mv $flo.* $sd.$ex" 
    rm $fl 
    mv $flo.* $sd.$ex 
#      else 
#        echo "$fl -- no SHORTDESC!" 
fi 
else 
  rm $$.tmp 
fi 
fi 
done
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information about this script? Or where you found it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Why don't you install `dos2unix` via your package manager.

2) Basically, line 13 is trying to run a file in your `PATH` (directories where your system searches for executables) that has the same name as the name of the current script.
Most likely, the scripted is intended to be run from a directory that's in your `PATH`.

Try placing it inside a directory listed in your `PATH` (see `echo $PATH`). If you can't write to any of those, append your `PATH` with a directory that you can write to and move the script there.

Then you shouldn't get that error.